# Can't install Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, xamarin, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 in my Windows 10 ENTERPRISE with an offline installer, but I have a problem with one workload: Xamarin
When I launch the visual studio installer and it arrives to the xamarin installation, I get this error:

```
Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Xamarin.Preparation,version=15.0.26621.2' failed to install.
Search URL
    https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Xamarin.Preparation;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1
Details
    Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\\cmd.exe" /C DEL /F /S /Q """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin"""
    Return code: 1
    Return code details: Incorrect function.
Log
    C:\Users\santiaj_Adm\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170825092313_007_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Xamarin.Preparation.log
Impacted workloads
    Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26606.0)
Impacted components
    Xamarin (Component.Xamarin,version=15.0.26711.1)
    Xamarin Workbooks (Component.Xamarin.Inspector,version=15.0.26606.0)
```

Any ideas about what can be wrong? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found your error here, a guy found a workaround you might want try that:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc0358cc-7554-4af3-9664-f892392d157e/package-microsoftvisualstudioxamarinpreparationversion150262280-failed-to-install?forum=vssetup

The workaround:

> I got the same issue, here is workaround Create the folder C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin Copy any files
>   to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin Run the setup
>   again. The root cause is that there is a command trying to delete some
>   files under xamarin folder and it failed if there is no file in
>   there.

If that doesn't work perhaps try this:

> Hi jenkstom,
>   If the above didn't help, how about trying with directly download and install the Xamarin packages from:
>   https://www.xamarin.com/download-it?_bt=101035044668&_bk=xamarin&_bm=e&gclid=Cj0KEQjwioHIBRCes6nP56Ti1IsBEiQAxxb5G2bCyosDgH-pB7hqJLAWdxB1dVFoZj_bufKCnO6AkKYaAtt88P8HAQ
>   Please temporarily disable the AV software and firewall during the installation.
>   As far as I know, you computer configuration meets the Xamarin install system requirements.
>   Best Regards,

Comment: thank you mate, but I still get this error, i don't know what is going on, maybe xamarin is not able in windows 10 enterprise edition?

Comment: I'd find that really weird. Did you follow the workaround? Like copying a random file in that map? I'm afraid I can't test anything for you since we don't know the reason behind the problem

Comment: Is there a reason why you using the offline installer btw? maybe try the other?

Comment: Yes, i tried the workaround, the reason i use the offline installer is for not downloading the full installation for each machine in the office, I tried to install online xamarin workload too, and still i get the problem, so is not about the downloaded packages :S

Comment: You speak of multiple machines, is it on every one that you have problems?

Comment: Yes, same problem in all devices

Comment: And you got admin rights on all devices? And you executed the installer as admin?

Comment: Yes, with elevated rights, it has no sense that only fails that workload installation

Comment: Ye i'm sorry, I don't understand it all, my last suggestion would be to go: https://www.xamarin.com/support and than create an incident so perhaps someone of the xamarin team can assist you

Comment: Yea, thx very much, I just opened an incidence, i'll post here their response :)